# new operator - exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, new-operator

I have a simple struct called node which holds a value + 2 pointers to next/previous nodes.

```
template <class T>
struct node {

     node<T> *prev = NULL;
     node<T> *next = NULL;
     T data;        
};
```

Here we have the function which adds a new node to the end.

```
void push_back( T val ) {           

    node<T> *n = new node<T>;   // create node to hold val
    n->data = val;              // set node data with val

    if ( node_count == 0 ) {     

        begins = n;             // begins points to first node          
    }
    else{

        ends->next = n;         // set next in ends
        n->prev = ends;         // set previous             
    }

    ends = n;                   // update ends
    node_count++;               // update list size
}
```

Finally, in main we attempt to create 30m linked nodes, each holding a unique int value.

```
int node_sum = 30000000;    
for (int i = 0; i != node_sum; i++){ 

    sl.push_back(i); 
}
```

Runtime:

Unhandled exception at 0x74C0C42D in exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0047F53C.

Here:

```
void push_back( T val ) {           

    node<T> *n = new node<T>;   // create node to hold val
```

When:

Creating the 29388062th or 2.9mnth node, the exact node number changes with each run, but it's always at least 2.938m.

I was thinking some kind of limit had been reached, but task manager says the entire windows platform is only using 4gb of ram which means there is 4gb spare.

Comment: Are you compiling as 32-bit? Because then all these small nodes with their allocation overhead could simply exhaust the available address space, if not your physical RAM.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit Windows and is your application 32 or 64 bit?  32 bit applications are limited to 2G of virtual address space.

Comment: `**node<T> *n = new node<T>;**`  Don't use stars to emphasize code.

Comment: x64 Win7 - x32 App. Resolved after switching to x64 app. Thanks!  I've just read x64 app is limited to 8TB...can that be right?  I tried to put the offending line of code in bold to make it more readable but it added stars instead.  Thanks for the edits, still getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply caused by you running out of memory.